# Prestashop 1.6 only one stock for all combinations

Tags: prestashop, combinations, stock, product-quantity

I am using Prestashop 1,6 and I have a several combinations in one product, but I need only one main stock quantity for all combinations. Is there a way how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is.

Answer (score 0):

With a custom module, you can do this : each time that you sell 1 combination, update stock all your combinations